# Profile link not working anymore

Tags: bug, profile-page, broken-link

I noticed that now when I click on a user's profile, the page doesn't load and shows an error saying:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

[image]

Comment: Seems to work *now*. But yes, it was broken probably 5 minutes ago.

Comment: @VLAZ Damn, just when I posted(within 1 or 2 minutes) the question it started working.

Comment: Damn those developers! Fixing the bugs before upstanding users can report them. :P